# Jenkins - Add download link to file if build fails

Tags: jenkins, save

I'm a little new to Jenkins, and I can't seem to figure this out. I have access to a Jenkins server that uses slaves to perform build jobs.

If a build fails, it stores a generated zip archive in a persistent Workspace directory for further debugging. The zip file is generated by a python script that keeps track of only the last 3 failed builds to conserve memory (i.e. 3 failed builds will result in 3 archives in the folder, but a fourth failed build will delete the oldest archive before adding the new one).

What I'm trying to do is add a download link to a failed Jenkins Run to allow users to quickly download the zip file that was generated for that build. But I'm really confused as to how approach this!

So I guess the question is, how could I add a download link to a Jenkins Run page to a file generated during that Run if it fails?

Example usage scenario:
1. I build some code :)
2. It fails :(
3. I download the zip file (from the Run page) with the generated debug files and find the fix :)
4. Space doesn't get filled up as zip files are kept only for the last 3 builds!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! I'm happy to provide more information if needed ^^ I am currently trying to use a system groovy script to do this, but perhaps artifacts would be more appropriate? I really can't seem to find good documentation on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are built in methods in Jenkins to allow this workflow:

- you can archive any artifact (in that case the zip) as post build step
- data retention strategy can be configured in the job via *Discard old builds* (*Advanced*).
- in order to send out customized mails on build failure with embedded download link you should review [Email Ext Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin); it allows you to configure individual texts for e.g. build failures where you could add the link to downloading the artifact.

Comment: Thank you :) I am currently trying to implement something really similar and I think I found the jenkins source code to do something similar.

If anyone else comes across this, then artifacts are indeed the way to go! To find out how to get fine control over which artifacts are stored or deleted, perhaps see this code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/StandardArtifactManager.java